# How to move to next scene using scene manager in Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a tutorial that is using unity 4 and they are using this:

```
Applicaiton.LoadLevel(Appliaction.loadedLevel +1);
```

in order to move on to the next scene. I am using unity 5, and it is telling me to use scene manager since the previous method is now obsolete.

What is the new code to replace the one above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Scene` struct has a `buildIndex` variable to store the index. Therefore, to load the next scene:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex; 
if(currentSceneIndex<SceneManager.sceneCount-1)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIndex + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement ; 
public class next_level : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void next_levl(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex +1 ) ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be very helpful

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.